# Rotating a set of 3D points against an arbitrary axis

Tags: graphics3d, vector, vector-calculus

I want to rotate a list of 3D points around unit vector (1,0,1) by the angle of Pi. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: See the help for `RotationTransform[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RotationTransform[Pi, {1, 0, 1}][points]
```